How to separate $TIME(n)$ and $L$?
I'm trying to prove that $TIME(n)\neq L$ by padding technique, yet it has a trouble:
Assume that $TIME(n)= L$, let $A\in TIME(n^2)\backslash TIME(n)$ so $A\notin L$. Let $A_{pad}=\{x01^{|x|^2-|x|-1}|x\in A\}$, it is easily to see that $A_{pad}\in TIME(n)$. Thus, we could decide $x\in A$ by padding it to $x01^{|x|^2-|x|-1}\in A_{pad}$ then deciding $A_{pad}$ in $O(\log n)$ space as assuming. When padding, however, we have used $O(n^2)$ space, so the algorithm consumes more than $O(\log n)$ space, which is not a contradiction as desired.
How could this problem be solved? Thanks in advanced!

The idea is to show $A$ log-space reduces to $A_{pad}\in L$ and thus $A\in L$ which is a contradiction. Log-space reduction works in a bit of an idiosyncratic way. You are allowed for the output to be larger-than-logarithmic in size, provided it is write-only.
So, given the input $x,$ you copy $x$ to the output, followed by a 0 (uses no space), then you compute and write down $|x|^2-|x|-1$ (uses $O(\log(|x|))$ space), then, write out $|x|^2-|x|-1$ ones to the output, counting it out by decrementing the number you wrote down.

"Write-only" is crucial, but "write-once" is not needed.

When we have the log-space reduction, we simulate the algorithm deciding $A_{pad}$ together with "rerunning from beginning" the reduction whenever the algorithm requests the next cell to maintain $O(\log n)$ space. If we write the $A_{pad}$ output directly, it will consume $O(n^2)$ space.

@minhquýlê Yes, that's the argument for why $L$ is closed under log-space reductions (that we can run the reduction algorithm many times, whenever we need a bit of its output, just waiting for the bit we need and discarding the rest of the output... in general, also need a small argument that the output of the log-space reduction is polynomial in size of input, though it obviously is in your specific case). I'm assuming that fact here and just arguing the reduction is log-space.
